# AngularJS Directive - Use same directive with different values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
app.directive("parishProCommunicant", function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'templates/admin/parishprocommunicant.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $compile) {
            $scope.labelNameCommunicant = "Name of Communicant";
            var modalParishProCommunicant = $('#modalParishProCommunicant');
            var dtParishProCommunicant = $('#datatable-pp-communicant');

            $scope.showModal = function () {
                // appendTo('body') prevents second modal to show in the first modal viewport
                modalParishProCommunicant.appendTo("body").modal('show');
            }

            $scope.closeModal = function () {
                modalParishProCommunicant.modal('hide');
            }

            /**
            * When the user selects a person
            **/
            $scope.selectCommunicant = function (id, names) {
                $scope.inputCommunicant = names;
                $scope.inputCommunicantId = id;
                $scope.closeModal();
            }

            initDatatable(dtParishProCommunicant, $compile, $scope);

            function initDatatable(dtUsers, $compile, $scope) {
                // code for initializing the datatable
            }
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, controller) {
            // alert(scope.ngModel);
        }
    }

});
```

...and the corresponding template `templates/admin/parishprocommunicant.html`

```
<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalParishProCommunicant" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Select Person</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="closeModal()" aria-label="Close">
                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body modal-lg">
                <table id="datatable-pp-communicant" class="table" style="width: 100%;">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Names</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Ref Number</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="closeModal()">Close
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--    End of Modal-->
```

...and using it as follows:

```
<parish-pro-communicant class=""
                        ></parish-pro-communicant>

<parish-pro-communicant class=""
                        ></parish-pro-communicant>

<parish-pro-communicant class=""
                        ></parish-pro-communicant>
```

The `gif` below shows how it works:

[image]

My challenge is having the directive referenced more than once because I need to achieve the following:

1. Pass the label names to the directive from the calling controller
2. Be able to access the `id` and `name` of the selected person (from the datatable) for each of the inputs
3. Be able to set the `id` and `name` from the calling controller

Basically, I should be able to pass data in a bidirectional manner from the calling controller to the directive and vice versa

Comment: Read [AngularJS Developer Guide -- Isolating the Scope of a Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).

Comment: Also read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Comment: @georgeawg Sure, will have a look at that.